# How to change video quality on full screen using Youtube's Iframe player API

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want the video on my page to be 360p on smaller screen and 720p or 1080p while changing it to full screen. I have tried appending "vq=hd720" to the embedded URL but it doesn't work which I think has become outdated. I have read the Iframe player API's documentation but couldn't really get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '3u1fu6f8Hto',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For play other video change the id of video

```
videoId: '<video_ID>',
```

Like:
    videoId: '3u1fu6f8Hto',

Comment: Hey,  I don't need to queue up videos. Is it possible to change a particular video-quality to a higher one on fullscreen? Hope you get it.  @Shivam